# Outlook randomly stops updating on VPN

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a computer with Outlook 2016 that randomly stops receiving email about twice a day. When this happens the little last connected to server at [Time] appears on the bottom of the Outlook window. Outlook can still send emails. A reboot or cycling the VPN off and on again fixes this issue temporarily.

Disabling cached exchange mode in Outlook fixed this for a few hours, but then in came back again.

Has anyone run into this before? Does anyone know of a permanent fix?

Comment: Is it an SMTP or Exchange account _(either a normal Exchange email or `hotmail.com`/`outlook.com`)_? Verify the Send/Receive options: File → Options → Advanced → Send/Reeive... → Check both the online and offline settings.

Comment: It is an exchange account

Comment: When Outlook stops updating on VPN, is the VPN still otherwise usable?

Comment: Yes, VPN still seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause I have seen of this issue is a VPN Timeout. Outlook pauses send/receive and VPN times out.

There are often two timeout values: Inactivity timeout (see if there is a rec-connect for this) and then timers in the Phase 1 and Phase 2 settings.  Check these

Comment: Thanks John, where can I find these values?

Comment: Look in your client VPN App and go through all settings.  Look in (or ask the Office) what settings they have and what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Do other users in the same working environment have the same issue as you?

After this issue occurs, if you manually Send/Receive All Folders, can Outlook sync normally? If yes, from the perspective of the client, you could [change your send/receive settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/change-send-receive-group-settings-7184f59d-c194-44d7-973a-7af568a918d0) to schedule an automatic send/receive every n minutes in Outlook and see if it could help.

Comment: Only a few users have this issue, there are quite a few that do not. The people with the issue have more email, but there are also people with the lots of email that do not have the issue. Manually doing a send and Receive and configuring Outlook to check for email every 5 minutes even when offline has no effect. Outlook maintains a connection to the server as per the connection status info under ctrl+right click on the Outlook Icon, but the inbox continues to update only sporadically. Adding an exclusion to the .ost in AV had no effect.